# Test networks not working

Tags: hardhat, goerli, alchemy, sepolia

I am using Hardhat, Alchemy and Goerli to test my SC. But for some reason NONE of my txns go through. They are all stuck in "Pending" within Alchemy. I have tried both Goerli and Sepolia test nets, and the same things is a happening with both. I have been dealing with this for a few days and I can't seem to get anywhere. Would anyone have ideas why?

Here is also my github to view my files: https://github.com/jaysnel/flash-loan

EDIT: I have sent upwards of 30gwei and waited 30+ min for those transactions